# How to classify data from object according to criteria given in another object, when the two objects have same keys?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have two objects that I need to combine somehow to achieve a desired output. Here's a toy example.

Let's say that I'm running an experiment about a new mice diet. I gathered 6 mice and fed each of them with a different diet. After several weeks, I weighted all mice and recorded each one's weight. Those weights are given in the following object:

```js
const postExperimentWeights = {
  mickey: 20,
  minnie: 11,
  jerry: 15,
  stuart: 33,
  gonzales: 17,
  pinky: 50,
};
```

To conclude whether any of the diets was successful, I have another data object, with the target weights that would be considered *bad*, *mediocre*, or *good*, per mouse.

```js
const targetWeights = {
  mickey: {
    belowIsBad: 15,
    aboveIsGood: 22,
  },
  minnie: {
    belowIsBad: 5,
    aboveIsGood: 10,
  },
  jerry: {
    belowIsBad: 16,
    aboveIsGood: 20,
  },
  stuart: {
    belowIsBad: 30,
    aboveIsGood: 40,
  },
  gonzales: {
    belowIsBad: 10,
    aboveIsGood: 15,
  },
  pinky: {
    belowIsBad: 60,
    aboveIsGood: 100,
  },
};
```

And my desired output is 3 variables, each of which contains an array of names:

```js
const good = ['minnie', 'gonzales']; // those were above their respective `aboveIsGood`
const mediocre = ['mickey', 'stuart']; // were between respective `belowIsBad` & `aboveIsGood`
const bad = ['jerry', 'pinky']; // below respective `belowIsBad`
```

Is there a fairly simple or elegant way to achieve the desired output?  I typically prefer to utilize a functional approach, but regardless would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi @Emman, can you please add what you've tried so far to achieve this and what you're specifically having trouble with in your attempt?

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons, I'm actually pretty clueless about how to approach this, as I'm new to the language. I guess that my first intuition is to use `if-else` blocks and `.push()` method, but I'm not sure it's the shortest approach, nor do I want to mutate variables.

Comment: Also, this is a simple question so I guess it had been asked/answered elsewhere, and is likely a duplicate. Nevertheless, I couldn't find a solution so maybe I'm not using the proper search terms.

Comment: Shouldn't "pinky" also be listed in `bad`?

Comment: @eol, whoops. You're right. Correcting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `reduce` using `push` instead of `concat`

```js
const postExperimentWeights = {mickey: 20,minnie: 11,jerry: 15,stuart: 33,gonzales: 17,pinky: 50,};
const targetWeights = {  mickey: {belowIsBad: 15,aboveIsGood: 22,},minnie: {belowIsBad: 5,aboveIsGood: 10,},jerry: {belowIsBad: 16,aboveIsGood: 20,},stuart: {belowIsBad: 30,aboveIsGood: 40,},gonzales: {belowIsBad: 10,aboveIsGood: 15,},pinky: {belowIsBad: 60,aboveIsGood: 100,},};

let res = Object.entries(postExperimentWeights).reduce((acc, [mouse,weight]) => {
    if (weight > targetWeights[mouse].aboveIsGood) acc.good.push(mouse)
    else if (targetWeights[mouse].belowIsBad < weight && weight <targetWeights[mouse].aboveIsGood) acc.mediocre.push(mouse)
    else if (targetWeights[mouse].belowIsBad > weight) acc.bad.push(mouse)
    return acc
}, {good: [],mediocre: [],bad: []})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop them one by one and push them in the right array.

```js
const postExperimentWeights = {
  mickey: 20,
  minnie: 11,
  jerry: 15,
  stuart: 33,
  gonzales: 17,
  pinky: 50,
};

good = []
bad = []
mediocre = []


const targetWeights = {
  mickey: {
    belowIsBad: 15,
    aboveIsGood: 22,
  },
  minnie: {
    belowIsBad: 5,
    aboveIsGood: 10,
  },
  jerry: {
    belowIsBad: 16,
    aboveIsGood: 20,
  },
  stuart: {
    belowIsBad: 30,
    aboveIsGood: 40,
  },
  gonzales: {
    belowIsBad: 10,
    aboveIsGood: 15,
  },
  pinky: {
    belowIsBad: 60,
    aboveIsGood: 100,
  },
};

for (mouse in postExperimentWeights) {
 let value = postExperimentWeights[mouse]
 if (value < targetWeights[mouse]["belowIsBad"]) {
    bad.push(mouse)
    continue
 }
 
  if (value > targetWeights[mouse]["aboveIsGood"]) {
    good.push(mouse)
    continue
    
 }
 
 mediocre.push(mouse)
 
}

console.log(good,bad,mediocre)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

So based on your data, you can do something like:

Description on the comments of the code

```
// object.entries will create a paired key-value 
// array of array i.e. [['mickey',20],['minnie', 11, <and so on>]]
Object.entries(postExperimentWeights).reduce(([prev, curr]) => {
  // key for the property name (person name), and its value.
  const [key, value]  = curr;

  // if it doesn't exist on the weigt, return skip? (you decide)
  if (targetWeights) {
    return prev;
  }

  if (targetWeights.belowIsBad < value) {
    // store it in its respective key based on condition
    return {
      bad: prev.bad.concat(key);
      ...prev,
    }
  }

  if (targetWeights.aboveIsGood > value) {
    // store it in its respective key based on condition
    return {
      good: prev.bad.concat(key);
      ...prev,
    }
  }
  
  // since this one is neither of the conditions above, its a mediocre 
  return {
      mediocre : prev.bad.concat(key);
      ...prev,
    }
}, {
  good: [],
  mediocre : [],
  bad: []
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate the expirement results using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and the simply compare with the target values:

```js
const postExperimentWeights = {
  mickey: 20,
  minnie: 11,
  jerry: 15,
  stuart: 33,
  gonzales: 17,
  pinky: 50,
};

const targetWeights = {
  mickey: {
    belowIsBad: 15,
    aboveIsGood: 22,
  },
  minnie: {
    belowIsBad: 5,
    aboveIsGood: 10,
  },
  jerry: {
    belowIsBad: 16,
    aboveIsGood: 20,
  },
  stuart: {
    belowIsBad: 30,
    aboveIsGood: 40,
  },
  gonzales: {
    belowIsBad: 10,
    aboveIsGood: 15,
  },
  pinky: {
    belowIsBad: 60,
    aboveIsGood: 100,
  },
};

function evaluateResults(input, target) {
 const good = [];
 const avg = [];
 const bad = [];
 for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(input)) {
   if(value < target[key].belowIsBad) {
    bad.push(key);
   }else if(value > target[key].aboveIsGood) {
    good.push(key);
   }else {
    avg.push(key);
   }
 }
  console.log("good:", good);
  console.log("avg:", avg);
  console.log("bad:", bad);
}

evaluateResults(postExperimentWeights,targetWeights);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code in simplest term

```
const mices = {
  mickey: 20,
  minnie: 11,
  jerry: 15,
  stuart: 33,
  gonzales: 17,
  pinky: 50
};

const targetWeights = {
  mickey: {
    belowIsBad: 15,
    aboveIsGood: 22
  },
  minnie: {
    belowIsBad: 5,
    aboveIsGood: 10
  },
  jerry: {
    belowIsBad: 16,
    aboveIsGood: 20
  },
  stuart: {
    belowIsBad: 30,
    aboveIsGood: 40
  },
  gonzales: {
    belowIsBad: 10,
    aboveIsGood: 15
  },
  pinky: {
    belowIsBad: 60,
    aboveIsGood: 100
  }
};

function findTheWeights(main, target) {
  const good = [];
  const mediocre = [];
  const bad = [];
  for (let mice in main) {
    const { belowIsBad, aboveIsGood } = target[mice];

    main[mice] > aboveIsGood
      ? good.push(mice)
      : main[mice] < belowIsBad
      ? bad.push(mice)
      : mediocre.push(mice);
  }

  return { good, bad, mediocre };
}

console.log(findTheWeights(mices, targetWeights));
```